# $\frac{d}{dx}(x^{x^{x}})$, $\int x^{nx}(1+\ln x)$

Tags: integration

Solve following

(1) Find $\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx}\left(x^{ x^{\large x}}\right)$

(2) Find $\displaystyle \int x^{nx}(1+\ln x)\,dx$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first one,

$$\begin{align}
y&=x^{x^x} \\
\ln{y} &=x^x\ln{x}\\
(\ln{y})' &= (x^x)'\ln{x} + x^x(\ln{x})' \\
\frac{y'}{y} &= (x^x)'\ln{x} + x^{x-1} \\
y'=\frac{d}{dx}(x^{x^x}) &= x^{x^x}\cdot \left[(x^x)'\ln{x} + x^{x-1} \right]
\end{align}$$

same reasoning can be applied to $z=x^x$ to find that

$$ (x^x)'=x^x\cdot(\ln{x}+1) $$

For the second, $x^{nx} = (x^x)^n$... Then pose $t=x^x$ in $\int x^{nx}(\ln{x}+1)\;\mathrm{d}x$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: For (1), rewrite $$x^{x^x}=e^{x^x\ln x}=e^{e^{x\ln x}\ln x}.$$ Apply chain and product rules as appropriate.

For (2), rewrite $$x^{nx}=e^{nx\ln x},$$ and try a $u$-substitution.